# .Net core MVC - Setting up a partial view to bind to multiple models

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I create a select dropdown list that can bind to multiple different models that have a property with a matching name?  In the example below I used **Criteria** as the matching property that is included in each model.

**Partial View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 propertiesdiv">
        <label><b>Saved Criteria: </b></label><br />
        <select class="form-control col-4 d-inline" asp-for="Criteria" id="savedCriteria"><option>Testing text 1</option></select>
    </div>
</div><br />
```

There is an error coming from the text `asp-for="Criteria"` that states "Represents an object whose operations will be resolved at runtime.  An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation."

**Model 1 Example**

```
public class Model1
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

**Model 2 Example**

```
public class Model2
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx  this has a few examples.. the `asp-items="ViewBag.Countries"` example might be what you're looking for

Comment: Could inheritance help here?  `Model1` and `Model2` both inherit from a base class containing `public IEnumerable<string> Criteria { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a lot of assumptions, however if you are using a `dynamic` object type (`ExpandoObject()`) in your controller to return multiple models, then you should be able to programmatically aggregate the desired data (`Criteria`) on the view side using Razor into one list and reference that list with the `asp-items` tag.

This is what I'm meaning, something like this:

```
    <select class="form-control col-4 d-inline" asp-for="Criteria" id="savedCriteria" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@Model1.Criteria.Union(@Model2.Criteria).Distinct()))">
        <option>Testing text 1</option>
    </select>
```

I haven't tested this code, but it's the idea I was going for.

Comment: I've got over 20 models that will all have this Criteria list. I used model1 and model2 as some simple examples to illustrate the general process that I was wanting.  I'm not sure this way of binding the models will be effective with such a large number of models.

Comment: Oh man, with 20 models, yeah the above is not scalable.  What is keeping you from  combining those into one list on the controller side rather than the view server page?

Comment: @EspressoBeans the list is unique to each model.  I might not be understanding your question correctly, but this list of objects is generated differently depending on the model that is being displayed in the view. Are you thinking if I make a new controller method that takes a string parameter with the model name, I could return the list that I'm looking for?

Comment: Ah ok, let me ask, all these models that have criteria list, are they passed to the view all at once (combined "god object"), or are they displayed singularly depending on what is desired to be viewed on the web page?

Comment: They are displayed singularly depending on the model.

Comment: Ok then I think I've misunderstood your problem.  It's not that you want to combine lists, instead you want your <select/> to be used dynamically for whichever "..Critera" model is passed to the view.  In that case, I would follow your train of thought of possibly creating a controller method that passes back the correct list based on the model name.  However that has a lot of tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an approach for binding multiple models into PartialViews.

But I do recommend utilizing ViewModels instead. Since your 2 models above use the same property (`Criteria`), just create a ViewModel with property common to those models you have and passed this ViewModel to your View (use ViewBag for passing the ViewModel to your View, if preferred).

From there, passed it to your PartialView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to receive `List<string>` as model for your partial view, and then use below code:

```
@model List<string>
<h1>_testPartial</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10 propertiesdiv">
        <label><b>Saved Criteria: </b></label><br />
        <select class="form-control col-4 d-inline" name="Criteria" id="savedCriteria" asp-for="@Model">
            <option>Testing text 1</option>              
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

For each main View, pass `Model.Criteria` to partial view.

```
@model Model1

<partial name="_testPartial" model="Model.Criteria"/>
```